# "Learn More" button misplaced in privilege tracker popup

Tags: bug, design

When you go to a high-enough-rep user's Activity page ([here's mine](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191178/laurel?tab=topactivity)) and click on the privilege progress bar, you'll see a popup like this:

> [image]

That button should be on the same line as the dark blue stripe but the font seems to be too wide. It displays fine if the user doesn't have much reputation:

> [image]

---

I'm using Chrome on Mac. Also, I have not enabled the "updated site theme".

Comment: It (with your profile) displays properly for me. I'm using Firefox on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's prepared for the new design. The font will change when it's completely rolled out.

I dislike this over-use of Arial. It's not necessary.

[image: New privilege box]

(New theme in Chrome on Windows)